# ConTeXt: Is it possible to use pgfplots groupplots library in ConTeXt mkiv?

Tags: pgfplots, context

I tried to use `pgfplots` `groupplots` library in ConTeXt. Therefore I loaded `pgfplots` and the library as described in the manual. It seems to load correctly when looking at the log file. Normal use of `pgfplots` does work too.

The environment `\startgroupplot`/`\stopgroupplot` is unknown, do I miss something?

I tried to get the example from the manual running.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\usepgfplotslibrary[groupplots]
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
}

\starttext

    \starttikzpicture
        \startgroupplot[group style={group size = 2 by 2}, height=3cm, width=3cm]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
        \stopgroupplot
    \stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

Comment: It is `\groupplot ... \endgroupplot`. Unfortunately, this library does not define ConTeXt synonyms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `\groupplot ... \endgroupplot`. Unfortunately, this library does not define ConTeXt synonyms, but to get the ConTeXt-y feeling you can easily define them yourself.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\usepgfplotslibrary[groupplots]
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
}

\unexpanded\def\startgroupplot{\groupplot}
\unexpanded\def\stopgroupplot{\endgroupplot}

\starttext

    \starttikzpicture
        \startgroupplot[group style={group size = 2 by 2}, height=3cm, width=3cm]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
        \stopgroupplot
    \stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```